# Django DETAIL: Failing row contains (..., null)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Error - DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, 2022-06-18 09:50:32.722841+00, 2022-06-18 00:00:00+00, NE, something, something, null).
I got 3 models: Patient => Hospitalization&Consults(ForeignKey=Patient), OneToMany. I know there, on "null" spot, must be the Patient ID, but I don t know how to get this ID.

> Models.py:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
     NameandLastName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     ...
class Consult(models.Model)
     Patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
     simptoms = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     option_pay = models.CharField(max_length = 40, choices = pay_method)
     ...
```

> Views.py

```
class Consult(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Consult
template_name = 'Manage/ConsultAdd.html'
form_class = forms.FromConsultAdd

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.autor = self.request.user
    messages.success(self.request, f"smth")
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

I think I have to put smth on views, but idk what.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add the lines of your code that raise that error? Maybe a traceback?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide `forms.FromConsultAdd` source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you're missing is the saving the instance, this lets Django know you updated the object.

Put this in your form_valid:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.autor = self.request.user
    form.instance.save()
    messages.success(self.request, f"smth")
    return super().form_valid(form)
```